# Contagem de caracteres de uma coluna em PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, caracteres

Eu tenho um dataframe onde eu consigo retornar as colunas que eu preciso, porém a coluna TELEFONE, contém números com 5 , 8 , 7 caracteres. Eu preciso retornar as colunas que contenham  apenas o telefone com 10 e 11 dígitos.

o script para selecionar as colunas seria o

`df.iloc [:, [0,1]]`

já pesquisei, em vários lugares e não consigo uma solução para me retornar apenas os telefones que contenham 10 e 11 digitos, mantendo a coluna nome.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a preocupação é somente com o número de caracteres, veja abaixo:

### Criar um dataframe teste

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"telefone": ['11111111111', '2222222222-', '333-333333', 'abcdef']})

print(df)
```

### Filtrado o dataframe

```
dataframe_filtrado = df[df.apply(lambda x: len(x["telefone"]) == 10 or len(x["telefone"]) == 11, axis=1)]

print(dataframe_filtrado)
      telefone
0  11111111111
1  2222222222-
2   333-333333
```

Caso queira testar algo mais detalhado, pode usar algo como:

```
def validar_telefone(row):
    if row["telefone"]) .......... :   # Testar se o telefone é válido baseado nos critérios.
        return True
    return False


dataframe_filtrado = df[df.apply(validar_telefone, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Paulo, obrigado pela sua ajuda e de fato funcionou em um arquivo teste, porém no meu arquivo ORIGINAL, encontro o erro     


---> 13 df_tels_fixo = df_tels_fixo[df_tels_fixo.apply(lambda x: len(x["TELEFONE"]) == 10 or len(x["TELEFONE"]) == 11, axis=1)]

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: O erro `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` mostra que sua coluna possui inteiros e nao string. Use `len(str(x["TELEFONE"]))`

Comment: Eu havia transformado a coluna telefone em string e funcionou, mas dessa forma fico muito mais simples e legível, mt obrigado !

Comment: Se achou que a resposta ajudou, nao esqueca de marcar como solucao e dar um upvote :)